# Strange beviour of replacing fragment in android

Tags: android, fragment

I am not able to understand this behavior of Fragment replacing. In my application, I am moving from FragmentA to FragmentB then FragmentC and then FragmentX and from FragmentX I am moving FragmentD and I am not keeping FragmentX in backstack but when I am popping fragments FragmentX is also called as other fragments are called (for testing purpose I have set log in every fragment’s onCreate() method). I have read when one pops out fragment onCreate() of that fragment is called. I am using below code for replacing fragments.

```
public void replaceFragment(BaseFragment fragment,boolean isToAddBackStack){
baseFragment = fragment;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_controller, fragment,        fragment.getName());
if(isToAddBackStack)
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getName());
else
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

And I am using below code for pooping fragments because I don’t want user to navigate back that's why I am pooping I did not find fragmentX in the list of FragmentManager but still FragmentX is pooped out.Below is the code I am using for pooping out the fragments

```
public void clearBackStack(){
    for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
       fm.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

My questions are why FragmentX is being called while popping out fragments when I am not keeping that in backstack ,is there any other way of popping out fragment (When I say popping out I mean clearing back stack).

Note: When I clear back stack as I mentioned I am not keeping FragmentX in back stack FragmentX's onCreate() is called and then my UI gets hanged. I am not able to find the reason. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in this part of your code -

```
if(isToAddBackStack)
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getName());
else
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Calling `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)` does not mean that the transaction will not be added to the back stack. It means that the transaction will be added, but without a name.

Remove the else statement from your code, and it should work.

```
...
if(isToAddBackStack)
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getName());
// no else here
...
```

Comment: One thing to be mentioned here I have already tried that as you mentioned but the same beviour I found.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Why don't you try using the above code and instead of popping the back stack yourself, let the fragment manager handle it, i.e. when the back button is pressed, the fragment manager automatically pops the latest entry on the back stack.

Comment: because I want to restrict the flow when a user is on fragment a and b user can go back but when user comes on fragment c I don't want user to go previous fragment that's why i am pooping